# Unable to submit form data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angualrJs and I have create simple popup in which user add some task and submit.There is one button as "Add task" which dynamically adds some fields and user enters detail into these field.
Now when user submit data then my data is not submitting properly and it got undefined.

Here is my html popup

```
  <div class="modal-header" >
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add Sprint</h3>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<form name="addSprintForm" data-ng-submit="taskDetail(story)" >

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sprintNo" data-ng-model="story.sprintno" placeholder="Sprint No">
      <div data-ng-repeat = "task in tasks track by $index">
      <br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="hide">Hide Task

        <input type="text"  data-ng-hide="hide" class="form-control" name="taskdetail" data-ng-model="story.taskdetail[$index]" placeholder="Task detail"><br/>
          <span ng-hide="hide">Total Stories</span>

          <select class="form-control" data-ng-hide="hide" name="sprints" data-ng-model="story.sprints[$index]" data-ng-options="sprint for sprint in totalStories" > </select> 
          {{$index}}
        <input type="button" data-ng-hide="hide" data-ng-show="$last"  class="remove pull-right" value="-" ng-click="removeTask()"><br/>

      </div>     

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="task"  ng-click="addTask()" value="Add tasks">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" >   
      </form>
```

My controller

```
 projectTrackerApp.controller('addSprintPopupCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

$scope.tasks = [];  

$scope.addTask=function(){

   var newItemNo = $scope.tasks.length+1;
$scope.tasks.push(newItemNo);
    console.log($scope.tasks)
}

 $scope.removeTask = function() {
var removeItem = $scope.tasks.length-1;
$scope.tasks.splice(removeItem);
 };

   var storiesArr = [];
 for(var i=0;i<16;i++) {
  storiesArr.push(i);
}
 $scope.totalStories = storiesArr;  



$scope.taskDetail=function(data){
     $scope.rohit=data;
alert(data)

 }


 }])
```

Comment: `data-ng-submit="taskDetail(tasks)"`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use directly the `scope` and `ng-model`:

```
$scope.story = {};
$scope.taskDetail = function(){
   console.log($scope.story);
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="addSprintForm" data-ng-submit="taskDetail()" >
```